# Send email with mailx/msmtp only works for root user

Tags: mailx, msmtp, armbian

I'm struggling to find a solution. I installed heirloom-mailx and msmtp following this [site](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1711217).
I can send emails (using gmail) as root user.
The problem is with non-root user: the messages go to a queue folder (/var/spool/mqueue) and never are sent.

I have little experience with linux. Could you help me?

System: Cubieboard 1 - 
Armbian Legacy Jessie server 3.4.112

```
.mailrc
set sendmail="/usr/bin/msmtp"
set message-sendmail-extra-arguments="-a gmail"
========================================================================================
.msmtprc
#Gmail account
defaults
logfile ~/msmtp.log

account gmail
auth on
host smtp.gmail.com
from XXX@gmail.com
auth on
tls on
# tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/cert.pem
tls_trust_file /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/Equifax_Secure_CA.crt
user XXX@gmail.com
password XXX
port 587

account default : gmail
========================================================================================
/var/log/mail.info
Oct 30 21:08:52 localhost sm-mta[4429]: u9U129DY004614: to=<XXX@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<root@localhost> (0/0), delay=22:06:43, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=11910461, relay=alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
```

mail.log:

```
Nov  1 20:08:27 localhost sendmail[15107]: uA1M8RXu015107: from=debian-transmission, size=380, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201611012208.uA1M8RXu015107@localhost>, relay=debian-transmission@localhost
Nov  1 20:08:27 localhost sm-mta[15111]: uA1M8RiY015111: from=<debian-transmission@localhost>, size=628, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201611012208.uA1M8RXu015107@localhost>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Nov  1 20:08:27 localhost sendmail[15107]: uA1M8RXu015107: to=XXX@gmail.com, ctladdr=debian-transmission (107/114), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30380, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (uA1M8RiY015111 Message accepted for delivery)
Nov  1 20:13:43 localhost sm-mta[15113]: uA1M8RiY015111: to=<XXX@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<debian-transmission@localhost> (107/114), delay=00:05:16, xdelay=00:05:16, mailer=esmtp, pri=120628, relay=alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [74.125.130.27], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
```

Debian-transmission is an user created by transmission. Transmission calls the bellow script after downloading:

```
printf "The torrent $TR_TORRENT_NAME was downloaded successfully at $TR_TIME_LOCATIME" | /usr/bin/mailx -s "Transmission downloaded : $TR_TORRENT_NAME" XXX@gmail.com
```

Maybe I could add the mailrc and msmtprc parameters to the script?

Comment: Do you see anything in `/var/log/maillog`?

Comment: I added the mail.log above. Maybe the debian-transmission user is using sendmail instead of mailx?

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the files `.mailrc` and `.msmtprc` also in your home directory.

Check if that program can read also configuration files from `/etc/`.

Comment: Thanks Giacomo for the tip. Now my user marcio can send email too. The problem is the debian-transmission user created by transmission torrent client. I tried creating /home/debian-transmission/.mailrc and .msmtprc but it does not work.